# Java: Get Size of JFrame Content

Tags: java, swing, jframe, frame, layout-manager

How do you get the actual content size of a `JFrame frame = new JFrame()`?

I am trying `frame.getContentPane().getSize()` but for some reason it keeps returning 0.

**CODE:**

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame();
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
frame.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
Dimension windowSize = frame.getContentPane().getSize();
System.out.println(windowSize);
frame.setVisible(true);
```

OUTPUT:

```
java.awt.Dimension[width=0,height=0]
```

Comment: When you retrieve the size, is the frame displayed? Show us some code.

Answer (score 3):

You can only get the size after the JFrame has been rendered, since otherwise the current size ***is*** [0, 0]. So make your call of `getSize()` only ***after*** `setVisible(true)`.

Just curious -- why do you need the information?

---

**Edit 1**
Per your code:

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame();
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
frame.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
// Dimension windowSize = frame.getContentPane().getSize();
// System.out.println(windowSize);
frame.setVisible(true);

Dimension windowSize = frame.getContentPane().getSize();
System.out.println(windowSize);
```

---

**Edit 2**
You state in comment:

> I need to set a panel as half the width of the content pane. Thanks

This information should have been in your original question since it is much more important than your trying to get the size. In fact your question is a great example of the [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

The solution is **not** to get the size, but to use a layout manager that will do this work for you, here a `GridLayout(1, 2)` could be your ticket.

Comment: I need to set a panel as half the width of the content pane. Thanks

Comment: @VinnieCaprarola: see **Edit 2**.

Comment: Try a BorderLayout, use the left and right panels (west and east); they will divide the panel with a vertical line and maintain the half-panel size through resizing with no further coding effort on your part.